# Pass generic return type of a Func

Tags: c#

I have method that looks like this:

```
public T DoMagic<T>(int a){
return defaultType(T);//this is just for the demo.
}
```

How can I pass this method as Func, I mean is it possible for Func to get return type as parameter and not have it declared when defined.
I need something like this /but one that does work/:

```
Func<T1, int,T1>  or  Func<T1><int,T1>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I pass in a func with a generic type parameter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12578965/how-can-i-pass-in-a-func-with-a-generic-type-parameter)

Comment: Shortly said, no it cant be done, I must use object as a concrete type, and cast it, after I after usage of the Func...Not ideal but ok... ty.

Comment: Whatever you pass it to would need to be generic like `MyMethod<T>(Func<int, T> func)` or you have to specify the like like `MyMethod(Func<int, string> func)` by doing `MyMethod(DoMagic<string>)`